# как мне перенести текст из одного текстового файла в другой, с изменением, подскажите код

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть текстовый документ:

```
mac address-table static 18:31:bf:c8:f8:c4 vlan 47 interface gigabitethernet1/0/4 secure
mac address-table static d4:5d:64:1e:88:7b vlan 47 interface gigabitethernet1/0/6 secure
mac address-table static d4:5d:64:1e:88:99 vlan 47 interface gigabitethernet1/0/1 secure
mac address-table static d4:5d:64:1e:88:b8 vlan 47 interface gigabitethernet1/0/8 secure
mac address-table static d4:5d:64:1e:88:e2 vlan 47 interface gigabitethernet1/0/2 secure
mac address-table static 80:5e:0c:27:3b:48 vlan 801 interface gigabitethernet1/0/3 secure
```

Результат:

```
xxxx:xxxx:xxxx vlan yy gigabitethernetZ/N/M
```

Comment: Прочитать текст, изменить, записать. Какие варианты-то?

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм такой:

1. Прочитать файл по строчкам - получится список строк
2. Каждую строчку разбить по пробелам - получится список из частей
   строки
3. Читая каждую строку выбрать только нужные куски и собрать их в
   нужном порядке - получится новый список в нужном формате
4. Собрать список с проблемами полученных частей - получится список
   готовых строк
5. Записать в файл список

Примерно такой алгоритм. Его можно делать по таким шагам, а можно шаги объединять.